# How can I send data from a onNewIntent() of the Activity to the VM of a Screen using Navigation Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I am developing an Android application with Jetpack Compose and Navigation Compose. The app is a multi-module application and consists of a single activity that uses the navigation library to navigate to different screens. I am currently implementing a login via Single Sign-On (SSO) that makes use of Chrome Custom Tabs. When the user logs in successfully and the app receives the deep link with the necessary data, I am able to retrieve this data from the intent in the main activity. However, I don't know how to forward this data to the view model of the login screen that is currently being displayed.

I would like to have a generic solution to send data provided via deep link intent to the ViewModel of the current screen displayed, no matter which screen it is. Is there an equivalent of `onNewIntent()` for the Navigation Compose that can be used to send data to the current destination on screen? I tried to navigate to the same destination using `launchSingleTop` but I don't know how to send data to the VM.

Answer (score 0):

you can access your intent in the login screen, and main compose function, by keeping a DiposableEffect of lifecycle observer and checking on start callback,
onNewIntent will trigger when we keep activity `launchMode="singleTask"` in the manifest.

```
val context = LocalContext.current
val lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
//handle deepLinks/noti. in home screen
DisposableEffect(lifecycleOwner) {
   
   
    // Create an observer that triggers our remembered callbacks
    // for sending analytics events
    val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
        if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_START) {
           val activity = context.findActivity()
    val intent = activity?.intent
    val destination = intent?.getStringExtra("destinationScreen")
    val queryParameter = intent?.data?.getQueryParameter("destinationScreen")
           //send this data to your viewmodel
        }
    }

    // Add the observer to the lifecycle
    lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)

    // When the effect leaves the Composition, remove the observer
    onDispose {
        lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
    }
}
```

here is findActivity extention function.

```
 fun Context.findActivity(): Activity? = when (this) {
    is Activity -> this
    is ContextWrapper -> baseContext.findActivity()
    else -> null
}
```

edited: code of the onNewIntent

```
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        if(this::navHostController.isInitialized) {
            navHostController.handleDeepLink(intent)
        }
    }
```

by adding this code you will get new intent for every new click of deeplink.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just tried it but I found some issues: 1) Once the deep link redirects me back to the App, the `activity.intent` that I'm receiving in `Event.ON_START` is still the previous intent, not the new one. 2) This is not actually reacting to new intents but to OnStart so, if the user sends the app to background and foreground, the intent will be triggered again, even if it is not a new intent.

Comment: @RobertoLeinardi I have added the code of __onNewewIntent__ , and once you read the intent from your composable screen clear the intent data to null, after you handle the link like __intent.data = null__